# Expected one assertion to be called but received zero

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm struggling with Jest, I just can't get it to work properly.

Function I wanna test:

```
fetchPosts() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Posts.find({}).then(posts => {
            if (posts) {
                resolve(posts)
            } else {
                reject("NOOOO")
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Test:

```
describe('fetching posts', () => {
    it('should get a list of posts in Array format', () => {
      expect.assertions(1);
      const result = posts.fetchPosts();
      return expect(result).resolves.toEqual(expect.any(Array));
    })
})
```

The `fetchPosts` function does return the whole list of posts. How can I make my test pass?

Comment: Since the result is a promise, did you try using `await`, something like `await expect(result).resolves.any(Array)`?

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: What your test is displaying when you run it?

Comment: *The fetchPosts function does return the whole list of posts.* - what does it return? What's error message? The problem depends on the contents of your database, doesn't it? `fetchPosts` uses promise construction antipattern. It will result in pending promise in case there's no posts.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html

Comment: @LucasCosta: Yes, tried this, doesn't work. Makes the same result.

Comment: @iagowp v8.9.1 and my test is displaying the error message in the title, and admin came 1m later and removed it from my post.

Comment: @estus the function fetchPosts does return the posts

Comment: Why are you sure it returns posts? In case it returns posts, it should work. You didn't provide error message. You didn't provide enough information. It's unclear what your case is.

Comment: Well the error message is the title, it was written in the original post but an admin came and removed it. I'm sure it returns the post because I have simply put that function in an endpoint and tried that endpoint.

Comment: As I said, at least one problem is that fetchPosts may return pending promise. Don't use `new Promise`.

Comment: Thanks but I'm a beginner, what's best to use in this case?

Comment: The function should contain `return Posts.find({})`. Nothing else. Please, let me know if it works. Consider using `@` in order for other users to receive notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Your fetchPost function is asynchronous. To make it work in your test you need to change some things.

1. Add 'async' to your test

   `it('should get a list of posts in Array format', async () => {...})`
2. Add 'await' before you call your async function
3. You need to `expect()` the result you want to get back from your function without the return statement.